# Correlation of parameters of 2-variable regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have the following problem from Agresti's book "Foundations of Generalized Linear Models":

2.9) In an ordinary linear model with two explanatory variables $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ having sample $corr(x_{*1},x_{*2}) > 0$, show that the estimated $corr(\hat{\beta_{1}},\hat{\beta_{2}}) < 0$.

So assuming that $E(y_{i}) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i1} + \beta_{2}x_{i2}$, how would I go about finding an expression for $corr(\hat{\beta_{1}},\hat{\beta_{2}})$? I know that:

$$Cov(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma_{y}^{2}(X^{T}X)^{-1} = \sigma_{y}^{2}\begin{pmatrix} n\ \ \  \ \ \ \sum_{i}x_{i1}\ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{i}x_{i2}\\ \sum_{i}x_{i1} \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{i}x_{i1}^{2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{i}x_{i1}x_{i2}\\ \sum_{i}x_{i2} \ \ \sum_{i}x_{i1}x_{i2}\ \ \sum_{i}x_{i2}^{2}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

so I was hoping I just take the element at $23$, and since $corr(x,y) = \frac{Cov(x,y)}{\sqrt{Var(x)Var(y)}}$, just divide it by the product of the elements at $22$ and $33$ ($ij$ is the $i$-th row and $j$-th column). Will my approach work? Will I have to do tedious simplifications? Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Using the generic formula for matrix inverses, with the matrix I specified in my post we can see that:

$$(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{23} = \frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}}{det(X^{T}X)}\left((\sum_{i}x_{i1})(\sum_{i}x_{i2}) - n(\sum_{i}x_{i1}x_{i2})\right) = \frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}}{det(X^{T}X)}\left( -n^{2}Cov(x_{1},x_{2})\right) $$

$$(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{22} = \frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}}{det(X^{T}X)}\left(n\sum_{i}x_{i2}^{2} - (\sum_{i}x_{i2})^{2}\right) = \frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}}{det(X^{T}X)}\left(n^{2}Var(x_{1}) \right)$$

$$(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{33} = \frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}}{det(X^{T}X)}\left(n\sum_{i}x_{i1}^{2} - (\sum_{i}x_{i1})^{2}\right) = \frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}}{det(X^{T}X)}\left(n^{2}Var(x_{2}) \right)$$

thus we have:

$$corr(\hat{\beta_{1}},\hat{\beta_{2}}) = \frac{(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{23}}{\sqrt{(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{22}(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{33}}} = \frac{-Cov(x_{1},x_{2})}{\sqrt{Var(x_{1})Var(x_{2})}} = -corr(x_{1},x_{2})$$

thus, we have that if $corr(x_{1},x_{2}) > 0$, that $corr(\hat{\beta_{1}},\hat{\beta_{2}}) < 0$